# Readkey in Pascal (Unknown Identifier)

Tags: pascal, graphic, turbo-pascal, readkey

I am learning how to use the graphic mode from Pascal (Using Turbo Pascal 5.5). This is a simple code, which shows me the graphic mode with some messages:

```
program GraficoPri
uses Graph;
var Driver, Modo : Integer;

begin
Driver := VGA;
Modo := VGAHi;
InitGraph(Driver,Modo,'P:BGI');
{Using DOSBox, P: is a mounted drive I created where all TP files are stored}
SetTextStyle(SansSerifFont,0,2);
SetColor(Red);
OutTextXY(120,60,'Welcome to graphic mode');
Writeln('Push any button to continue'};
Readkey;
CloseGraph;
End.
```

Well, the problem I'm having is that "Readkey;" is giving me a 'Unknown Identifier' error. I tried changing the line with "Readln;" and it worked fine. What is the problem here?
Thank you!

Comment: AFAIR you need `uses crt;` for that

Comment: And you have a syntax error in `Writeln` line, `}` instead of `)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos I used crt and it didn't work. But well, it was more like and aesthetical issue for the game. I could handle it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Readkey is from the crt library, so you need to change

```
uses graph
```

to

```
uses wincrt, graph
```

Also, readkey is always used as a variable declaration. For example,

```
ch := readkey;
```

If you just want to push a button to continue, you should use a repeat-until keypressed loop.

```
repeat
until keypressed;
```

This will wait and do nothing until the user presses a key.

Comment: `WinCRT` was introduced later, no? It was just `CRT` in 5.5, if memory serves.